# Reading text file, matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am reading a text file 'mytext.text' in matlab. Data file looks like:

```
1   -4436.6910  415.1843    -3019.7497  1,3,4,5,21,23

2   -4366.4541  1353.9975   -3085.1166  1,3,4,23
```

....

I  don't know the length of Col5. How can I read it in matlab?

```
fid=fopen( 'mytext.text','r');

Grdata = textscan(fid, '%d %f %f  %f  (Col 5 what should be)% This line is 
problem%  

fclose(fid);
```

Any help.

Comment: are the commas an integral part of the file format? If the commas can be replaced with spaces (like for the first 3 numbers), you might be able to use `dlmread`. The resulting data that is read will have dimensions that can tell you about which columns are missing etc. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to read the last column as string, then convert it to numbers afterward.

```
fid = fopen('file.dat','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %s', ...
    'Delimiter',' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true, 'CollectOutput',true);
fclose(fid);

C = [num2cell(C{1}) cellfun(@str2num, C{2}, 'UniformOutput',false)]
```

The resulting cell-array:

```
C = 
    [1]    [-4436.7]    [415.18]    [-3019.7]    [1x6 double]
    [2]    [-4366.5]    [  1354]    [-3085.1]    [1x4 double]
```

with:

```
>> C{1,end}
ans =
     1     3     4     5    21    23
>> C{2,end}
ans =
     1     3     4    23
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a single line do

```
% Read at most 4 elements
data1234 = fscanf (fid, '%d %f %f %f', 4);
% Read as many elements as possible, stop when no ',' is found
data5 = fscanf (fid, '%d,');
```

Continue reading lines until you reached the end of the file (save the data from each line before doing that). So you need some loop that continues doing this untill the file ends.